# Swagger for PHP - array of objects as param

Tags: php, swagger

```
"zircote/swagger-php": "^2.0"`
```

I want to submit an array of objects. The following notation does not work:

```
*     @SWG\Parameter(
*          name="foo",
*          in="query",
*          required=true,
*          type="array",
*          @SWG\Items(
*              type="object",
*              @SWG\Property(
*                  property="id",
*                  type="string"
*              ),
*              @SWG\Property(
*                  property="position",
*                  type="string"
*              )
*          )
*     ),
```

This error is thrown:

```
User Notice: @SWG\Items()->type="object" not allowed inside a @SWG\Parameter() 
must be "string", "number", "integer", "boolean", "array" in D:\...
```

I could do an array of json strings, but i dont like this idea. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Based on the documentation, your object syntax is wrong and I do not see any syntax for building an array. See https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/#object

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I dont want to submit an object but an array of objects. You see `type="array"` in my example?

Comment: I missed that. Regardless, your syntax looks different than the documentation at https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/#array Is there a reason for this? Are you using a different version?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus What is written in the link is exactly what i am trying to do with Doctrine notation. It fails. My swagger-php version is also written on top.